# expo react native camera did not work

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I am using the basic code from [here](https://github.com/expo/camerja) to get the camera working. The only difference is that I did not make a standalone camera app instead implement the code to other app (opening the camera from button inside the app)

I am following the code exactly but the camera would not take the picture and save it. There is even a warning saying

```
[Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: TypeError: expected dynamic type `string', but had type `object']
```

I recheck the code and I am pretty sure it came from this part

```
takePicture = async function() {
if (this.camera) {
  this.camera.takePictureAsync().then(data => {
    FileSystem.moveAsync({
      from: data,
      to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state.photoId}.jpg`,
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        photoId: this.state.photoId + 1,
      });
      Vibration.vibrate();
    });
  });
}
  };
```

The snap button did not take the picture.

I did a console log and found out the following for `takePictureAsync()`

```
if (this.camera) {
  this.camera.takePictureAsync().then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

and this is the result

```
Object {
  "height": 1920,
  "uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540lily%252Fmotion/Camera/e501458d-f081-47b5-b7ac-6742f8e8d61e.jpg",
  "width": 1080,
}
```

Is this why it says in the warning `expected dynamic type 'string', but had type 'object']` ? and possible reason why the app did not take the picture?

If it is, how should I fix this?

Thank you for your help.

My `package.json`

```
"expo": "^22.0.4",
"native-base": "^2.3.3",
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.1.tar.gz"
```

Comment: can you post the code of the function where you printed the log?

Comment: @Ishita Sinha please refer to my question. I have edited it to show the code I used to print the log

Comment: Use `from: data.uri` instead of `from: data`. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you did take a picture!  Now you just need to save it somewhere...

```
FileSystem.moveAsync({
      from: data,
      to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${this.state.photoId}.jpg`,
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        photoId: this.state.photoId + 1,
      });
      Vibration.vibrate();
    });
```

The code you provided is using the [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem.html#content) to save your photo locally inside the application. Your photo will be saved to something like this: `{documentsDirectory}/photos/Photo_{0}.jpg`

---

If you would like to save your image to the Camera Roll you should use the React Native [CameraRoll API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html).

You would use the static method `await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(photoUri)`

Comment: ok, I think I understand the part `saving the photo locally inside the application` but when I check inside the application, there is no picture saved locally there. I get it that it is just a warning but could it be there is other part that I missed? I run the app mainly on android